# Two different MCU , different output but none was right?

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I write this simple code to check my new burner :

```
#include<avr/io.h>

void main(void)
{
DDRC = 0xFF;  //high pins
PORTC=0x00;


while(1)
{

PORTC=0xFF;
}
}
```

I use Extreme burner software to burn . My burner seems to work fine. It burn the code (said by the burner software ) but output is not as I expected.
I burn two ATmega32 .
For first one , PC2 , PC3, PC4 give high output (around 4.3 volt) and rest is low (around 1.7 volt) .
For second one , PC0 , PC1 , PC7 pin high output and rest is low. 
I can't understand why ???
anyone can explain and give me a solution ??
Thanks  [image]

Comment: How are the fuses programmed on the devices?

Comment: What is connected to the micro controller? just power and ground or any other devices?

Comment: fuse is default.  both MCU is new.  I just unpack it and burn the code.@ Ignacio

Comment: Just power, ground and LED with small resistor at PORTC

Comment: Can you add a photo of the circuit (or a link) and a circuit showing exactly the pins that are connected?

Comment: Can you try any other port? Instead of Port C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATmega32 fuse bits are enabled JTAG interface on PC2...PC5 by default.
If you want to use PC2...PC5 in your project, you should disable JTAG by unprogrammed JTAGEN fuse bit.